# Find the time that 90% of tickets are processed in?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

My boss wants metrics on our ticket processing system, and one of the metrics he wants is "the 90% time" which he defines as the time it takes 90% of the tickets to be processed. I guess he's considering that 10% are anomalous can be ignored. I would like this to at least approach some statistical validity. So I've got a list of the times that I throw into a numpy array. This is the code I've come up with.

```
import numpy as np

inliers = data[data<np.percentile(data, 90)]
ninety_time = inliers.max()
```

Is this valid? Is there a better way?

Comment: are the times you throw in cumulative or incremental?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis incremental. The time taken to process 1 ticket is one entry in the array.

Comment: the most *statistically-correct* process i can think of would be to get the time column, isolate it, sort it, eliminate an equal amount of entries from the front and back (the fastest and slowest ones; `0.05 * len(array)` from each side so that you end up with 90% of the total) and then just sum whats left up.

Answer (score 2):

Percentiles are a statistically perfectly valid approach. They are used to provide robust descriptions of the data. For example the 50% percentile is the median, and box-plots typically show the 25%, 50%, and 75% percentiles to give an idea of the range covered by data.

The 90% percentile can be seen as a rather naive and rough estimate of the maximum value that is less vulnerable to outliers than the actual max-value. (Obviously, it is somewhat biased - it will always be less than the true maximum.) Use this interpretation with care. It's safest to see the 90% percentile as what it is - a value where 90% of the data below and 10% above.

Your code is somewhat redundant as the `percentile(data, 90)` returns the value where 90% of the elements in data are lower or equal. So I would say this is exactly the 90% time and there is no need to compute the value for <90%. For a large number of samples and continous values the difference between <=90% and <90% will vanish anyway.